# How can I create a font from my handwriting?

Tags: typography, typefaces

A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=font+from+your+handwriting) turns up many websites that claim to make a customized script font from a sample of your handwriting. How do they compare, and would you recommend any such service? Are there online tools (free or open-source preferably) that can achieve this goal?

Comment: Double? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/building-hand-written-fonts-for-lettering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried Fontifier before and it's worked pretty well.

http://www.fontifier.com/

Hopefully it'll be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, you could also try icomoon. The brilliant result of that would be that you could also use your font online. Hurrah for vectors! http://icomoon.io/